# Heroky upload node app and Java jar

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, heroku, jar

I am developing a node.js app at the moment. I plan to host in on heroku.

The catch is this app relies on a jar file, that i will have to run obviously.

Is this possible on heroku, to run java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the JVM buildpack to your app:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add -i 1 heroku/jvm
```

Then redeploy with:

```
$ git commit -m "Add JVM" --allow-empty
$ git push heroku master
```

After this, the `java` command will be available at runtime.

Comment: Thank you so much! If it's possible to run node.js alongside with java i will continue with the development of my app! Your comment enabled me to do this!